# C# Look for matches in array

Tags: c#

Im trying to see if a certain element exists in my array.
I have a function where i add elements to my array and a search function that returns true if the element exists. I keep getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

I have a field:

```
int [] Items;
```

This is the search function:

```
public bool Search(int item)
{

    bool isInArray = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < Items.Length; i++) // ERROR HERE
    {
        if (Items[i] == item)
        {
            isInArray = true;
            break;
        }

    }
    return isInArray;


}
```

This is the add Function:

```
public void Add(int item)
{

    if (Items == null)
    {
        Items = new int[1];
    }
    else
    {
        Array.Resize<int>(ref Items, Items.Length + 1);
    }
    Items[Items.Length - 1] = item;
}
```

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: Where is your error occuring? Is your array initialized?

Comment: Theres only 1 place it could happen. What is Items? Where do you set it's value?

Comment: Why you do not want to use `List<int>` which will give you exactly what you want? `Add` and `IndexOf` instead of `Search`

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko The Items array get its value from userinput via the add function. Check the link

Comment: @outcoldman Thanks but i have to use an array.

Comment: Do you call the add function before the search function? that seems to be the big question here.

Comment: What error? What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: What is your `Main` code? how do you run this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Items` need to be intialized , for example in the constructor. E.g. Items = new int[10]

Comment: Thanks but the size of the array should be the same as the total elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your Items is null as long as you don't add at least one.

Comment: Im calling the add function in my form before the contain function so it should be null right?

Comment: Well, set a breakpoint to the lines where you initialize the array to something else than null and to your loop and see if Items is null.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < Items.Length; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < (Items?? (Items = new int[0])).Length; i++)
```

Comment: This will kill logic, because if somebody will try to Search before Add - Items will have first element with 0.

Comment: ahhh, yes, then the code should create ZERO length array for Items, not a single element array. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Check for null before you will do loop:

```
public bool Search(int item)
{
    bool isInArray = false;
    if (Items != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.Length; i++) // ERROR HERE
        {
            if (Items[i] == item)
            {
                isInArray = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return isInArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool Search(int item)
{
    return Array.IndexOf(Items, item) > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Maybe this would work.